# select string after second space

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

I have a column containning different names, I would like to get all the strings after the second space of characters.

My example.

```
df <- data.frame(col = c("Adenia macrophylla", "Adinobotrys atropurpureus (Wall.) Dunn", "Ardisia purpurea Reinw. ex Blume"))
```

My desired outcome like this

```
                                     col
1                                    
2                           (Wall.) Dunn
3                        Reinw. ex Blume
```

Any sugesstions for me? The way before I did is to `separate` them and `unite`, but I consider whether we have any fancy way or better to do it, since I already have many columns.

*Update*
Just solve it

```
xx %>% 
  mutate(col = str_pad(col, 20,"right")) %>% 
  mutate(col = str_remove(col, '\\w+\\s\\w+\\s'))
```

Thanks @Ronak and @U12-Forward for providing me `regex`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `sub` -

```
sub('\\w+\\s\\w+\\s', '', df$col)
#[1] "(Wall.) Dunn"    "Reinw. ex Blume"
#Also
#sub('.*?\\s.*?\\s', '', df$col)
```

If you want a `tidyverse` answer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(val = str_remove(col, '\\w+\\s\\w+\\s'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to select string after n space's it might be good to use repetition in `sub`.

```
sub("([^ ]* ){2}(.*)|.*", "\\2", df$col)
#sub("([^ ]* ){2}|.*", "", df$col, perl=TRUE) #Alternative
#[1] ""                "(Wall.) Dunn"    "Reinw. ex Blume"
```

`[^ ]` get everything but not a space `*` 0 to n times,   match a space, `{2}` match it two times, `.*` match everything.

Answer (score 0):

Or use this regex:

```
df$col <- sub('^\\S+\\s+\\S+', '', df$col)
```

Output `df`:

```
> df
               col
1                 
2     (Wall.) Dunn
3  Reinw. ex Blume
>
```

Comment: can we do for example add a right outer space of a character, and remove everything before the second space as you and @Ronak mention?

Comment: @Anh Do you mean `sub('^\\S+\\s+\\S+', ' ', df$col)`